# How to print the 32 different combinations of a 5-digit access code(2 choices per number(2^5))?

Tags: c, arrays, input, combinations

I am trying to write a program that scans in a 5-digit key pad access code and then returns the 32 different ways the access code could be mimicked. This means that each button has 2 possible choices; therefore, each 5-digit access code has 2^5 = 32 combinations. My program successfully returns which buttons the user has pressed and how many times, however I've come to a brick wall with implementing a piece of code for the various combinations that are equivalent. The question is: how can I implement code to return the 32 other equivalent access codes?

The key pad looks something like this:

(Buttons 1-5)

Button 1: 1 & 2

Button 2: 3 & 4

Button 3: 4 & 6

Button 4: 7 & 8

Button 5: 9 & 0

```
/*Headers*/
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 5


int main (void){

  /***** Key Pad ******/
   /*   (Buttons 1-5)

Button 1: 1 & 2

Button 2: 3 & 4

Button 3: 4 & 6

Button 4: 7 & 8

Button 5: 9 & 0 */
/***** Key Pad**** */


 /* Data */
unsigned int input1[2];
unsigned int input2[2];
unsigned int input3[2];
unsigned int input4[2];
unsigned int input5[2];
unsigned int x=0;
unsigned int i=0;
unsigned int j=0;
unsigned int k=0;
unsigned int l=0;
unsigned int m=0;
unsigned int z=0;


for(z=0;z<15;z++){

printf("--");

}
printf("\n");
printf("\t*** KEY PAD ***\n");
printf("Button 1: 1 or 2\n");
printf("Button 2: 3 or 4\n");
printf("Button 3: 5 or 6\n");
printf("Button 4: 7 or 8\n");
printf("Button 5: 9 or 0\n");


for(z=0;z<15;z++){

printf("--");

}

printf("\n");

/* Code to enter integers into the key pad */
printf("Enter the five digit lab access code\n");
printf("Type one number at a time and press 'enter' after each digit\n");
scanf("%d%d%d%d%d", &input1, &input2, &input3, &input4, &input5);




if( input1 == 1 || input1 == 2){
      input1[0] = 2;
      input1[1] = 1;

         }else{
if(input1 == 3 || input1 == 4){
       input1[0] = 4;
       input1[1] = 3;

         }else{
if(input1 == 5 || input1 == 6){
       input1[0] = 6;
       input1[1] = 5;

         }else{
if(input1 == 7 || input1 == 8){
      input1[0] = 8;
      input1[1] = 7;

         }else{
if(input1 == 9 || input1 == 0){
      input1[0] = 9;
      input1[1] = 0;

}}}}}//End IF/ELSE





if( input2 == 1 || input2 == 2){
      input2[0] = 2;
      input2[1] = 1;

         }else{
if(input2 == 3 || input2 == 4){
       input2[0] = 4;
       input2[1] = 3;


         }else{
if(input2 == 5 || input2 == 6){
       input2[0] = 6;
       input2[1] = 5;

         }else{
if(input2 == 7 || input2 == 8){
       input2[0] = 8;
       input2[1] = 7;

         }else{
if(input2 == 9 || input2 == 0){
       input2[0] = 9;
       input2[1] = 0;

}}}}}//End IF/ELSE



 if( input3 == 1 || input3 == 2){
      input3[0] = 2;
      input3[1] = 1;

         }else{
 if(input3 == 3 || input3 == 4){
     input3[0] = 4;
     input3[1] = 3;

         }else{
 if(input3 == 5 || input3 == 6){
     input3[0] = 6;
     input3[1] = 5;

         }else{
if(input3 == 7 || input3 == 8){
    input3[0] = 8;
    input3[1] = 7;

         }else{
if(input3 == 9 || input3 == 0){
     input3[0] = 9;
     input1[1] = 0;

}}}}}//End IF/ELSE




if( input4 == 1 || input4 == 2){
     input4[0] = 2;
     input4[1] = 1;

         }else{
if(input4 == 3 || input4 == 4){
     input4[0] = 4;
     input4[1] = 3;

         }else{
if(input4 == 5 || input4 == 6){
     input4[0] = 6;
     input4[1] = 5;

         }else{
if(input4 == 7 || input4 == 8){
     input4[0] = 8;
     input4[1] = 7;

         }else{
if(input4 == 9 || input4 == 0){
     input4[0] = 9;
     input4[1] = 0;

 }}}}}//End IF/ELSE




 if( input5 == 1 || input5 == 2){
     input5[0] = 2;
     input5[1] = 1;


         }else{
if(input5 == 3 || input5 == 4){
     input5[0] = 4;
     input5[1] = 3;

         }else{
if(input5 == 5 || input5 == 6){
     input5[0] = 6;
     input1[1] = 5;

         }else{
if(input5 == 7 || input5 == 8){
     input5[0] = 8;
     input5[1] = 7;

         }else{
if(input5 == 9 || input5 == 0){
     input5[0] = 9;
     input5[1] = 0;

 }}}}}



for (i=0; i<2; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<2; j++) {
        for (k=0; k<2; k++) {
           for (l=0; l<2; l++) {
              for (m=0; m<2; m++) {


  printf("%d%d%d%d%d\n", input1[i], input2[j], input3[k], input4[l], input5[m]);
        }
    }
    }

    }

 }




 printf("\n\n");


 for(z=0;z<15;z++){

 printf("--");

 }

 printf("\n\n");

         }//End of Main
```

Comment: Your 32 combinations can be represented by the binary numbers from `00000` through to `11111`. Run through these numbers, and substitute option 1 for `0` and option 2 for `1`.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: So if, as in your example, you've typed `00000` (by pressing button 5 five times), you know for each press, the options are 0 or 9. Taking the first 3 binary numbers, `00000`, `00001`, `00010`, if you map `0` to 0 and `1` to 9, you will get these three combinations: 00000, 00009, 00090. Do this for all 32 numbers between 0 and 31, and you will have all the combinations for that particular input.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Here's an example, in java, for 3 digits.  I use a 2 element array for each digit, it's initialized to your button 0 settings, you need logic to initialize it to the actual button setttings, but the idea is pretty straightforward, you should be able to extend this easily:

```
    int[] dig1 = new int[2];
    int[] dig2 = new int[2];
    int[] dig3 = new int[2];
    dig1[0] = 0;
    dig1[1] = 9;
    dig2[0] = 0;
    dig2[1] = 9;
    dig3[0] = 0;
    dig3[1] = 9;
    for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<2; j++) {
            for (int k=0; k<2; k++) {
                System.out.println(dig1[i]+" " + dig2[j] + " "+dig3[k]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why a Java answer for a C question?

Comment: I can dig it, its still a little helpful.

Comment: Just lazy I guess, there's nothing special about the language here, the OP needed help with the algorithm.

Comment: @RaoulDuke, why only a "little helpful", are you still not clear how to solve your problem?  Create a 2-element array for each digit, set the two values to the allowed values (e.g. if the keypad entry for digit 1 is 2 the set the values as 3 and 4) then iterate through 5 nested loops to generate all the equivalent series.